# My makefile could not find header file

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have write a simple makefile

```
 1 LIBS= -L /usr/local/pgsql/lib
 2 INCL= -I /usr/local/pgsql/include -I/home/name/
 3 
 4 pg: pg.o
 5     gcc -o  pg pg.o  $(LIBS) -lpq
 6 
 7 pg.o: pg.c
 8     gcc -c $(INCL) $(LIBS) pg.c
```

Under the folder of name, there are three files: pg.c, timer.c, timer.h
but it reports error of could not find timefunctions.  what's wrong with my makefile? thanks. 
The error is

```
 gcc -o  pg pg.o  -L /usr/local/pgsql/lib -lpq
 pg.o: In function `main':
 pg.c:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `createTimer'
 pg.c:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `startTimer'
 pg.c:(.text+0x167): undefined reference to `endTimer'
 ...
 pg.c:(.text+0x214): undefined reference to `displayTimer'
 pg.c:(.text+0x220): undefined reference to `destroyTimer'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 make: *** [pg] Error 1
```

Comment: If you are in `/home/name` and that's where your `.c` and `timer.h` files are, then it should find `timer.h` even without the `-I`. Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere? What function does it say is missing? And is it defined properly in `timer.h`? And is it a compiler error or a linker error?

Comment: I added error information. @ lurker. The code should be no problem, I used it many times...I doubt the makefile ...

Comment: Are those undefined timer functions defined in `pg.c`? Not doubting the `.c` or `.h` contents, just wondering where the linker is supposed to find things. And I don't know if it matters, but all the examples I've seen, and I have only personally used, no space between `-L` and the lib path name.

Comment: they are defined in timer.h

Comment: They're *declared* in `timer.h`. Are they really *defined* (implemented) there?

Comment: I would guess they're *defined* in `timer.c`, which you are not compiling or linking in your current make recipes...

Comment: How could I revise the makefile? @twalberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us enough information to be certain, but it might be enough to add `timer.o` to the prerequisite list of the `pg` rule:

```
pg: pg.o timer.o
    gcc -o pg $^ $(LIBS) -lpq
```